# Master Device Is Lost and Valid Dump Does Not Exist (SYBASE ASE 15.0)

Tags: database, t-sql, sybase, sap-ase

I have the following issue , the physical device of the master db is damaged and a valid dump of master doesn´t exist , I´m using ASE 15.0 version .

How can a recover my master db and my users and logins ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the devices of the other databases are not damaged and you have the device creation scripts you can restore the devices with disk reinit and disk refit , after that just query the users from each database from sysusers , get the name , the creation id and add them with sp_loggin in the correct order.

Answer (score 0):

if you don't have backup and physical device is damaged I don't see a way to recover. But if you have database dump you could load it on other Sybase server and you will see created users, from there you could know at least user names.